# Using pods with Playgrounds in Xcode 9 (beta)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9-beta

I would like to use some CocoaPod libraries in playgrounds, but can't see a way of linking the playground with a target in **Xcode 9 (beta 4)**.  I think this is doable in earlier Xcode versions, but don't have an earlier version of Xcode on my current machine.

Creating a playground creates it as part of the group *Unsaved Xcode Document* - and opens it in a separate window.

[image]

**How can I install pods which can be imported in the playground?** *(through a workspace or project if needed)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I upgraded to 9 yesterday and this morning found that I could no longer add playgrounds to my workspace with a right click/New File. The template isn't there. 
The solution is to create the new playground. Open in Finder. Drag it onto the workspace. It now belongs to the workspace and has access to the podfile.

Comment: Needs drag full folder to project?

Comment: just playground file , but make sure you dragged it under workspace directory not project or pods directories

Comment: This still working out for you? Can't get it working even if I add it to workspace or project...